# How to make a transparent background?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If the question has been asked before, please forgive me and send the link to it. But i personally have not seen this asked here before.

My goal is to make a transparent background, such that the wallpaper of the laptop's desktop is the one being seen on the background of the webpage. Do all this while keeping the content of the webpage visible. Only HTML, CSS, and Javascript is allowed. Thanks in advance!

```
    body{
    background color: (0,0,0,1);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    opacity: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Have you made any code attempts so far? If so, show us and we can help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to demonstrate what you've tried and where you got stuck. We're not here to do all your coding for you. And to whomever upvoted this question, please identify yourself. We need to revoke your account.

Comment: I do not believe  this is possible. As far as I know, the canvas beneath the canvas is white.

Comment: As @MonkeyZeus already wrote, I also think this is not possible..

Comment: you know what i want me ... to have a transparent background to see the wall behind my laptop, you think it's possible ?

Comment: Proof of non-working concept: `<html style="background-color: transparent;"></html>`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus the proof is to simply open your browser with no page ...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/ZxgvOO doesn't work, as already said, this is not possible...

Comment: @MrBuggy correct, it was meant to be the shortest code possible to prove that it does not work...

Comment: @TemaniAfif it depends. You ever press `F12` on a new tab and check out the element explorer?

Comment: i edited the post, i have tried the code in my edit post. but it does not work

Comment: your code is completely wrong and has no meaning ... what's `(0,0,0,1)` ?

Comment: If you find out how to get the path to the image which is set as background of your desktop, you could style the body with the same image as background image and than put a div with opacity...;-) this would be the only way...

Comment: I think you want to program an own browser.

Comment: @MrBuggy That idea sounds good, but for security reasons, won't be possible.

Comment: the 1 in the (0,0,0,1) was meant to be for the opacity of the background?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks, I also thought this could be a nice idea to solve this strange request :D

Comment: oh wait i forgot there is supposed to be rgba before the parenthesis

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible because the web client is a program running on the device (usually written in C/C++/Objective C) and a web page exists on the web client's document "slate" (default area of client UI devoted to displaying the HTML document).

Your question isn't how to make a web page background transparent (that's easy), it's how to make the web client application background transparent and that's not going to be possible with HTML, CSS and JavaScript (if at all).